# WebSphere 9 Apache CXF - Bean validation throws Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere, cxf, hibernate-validator

I got a project with Apache CXF with Hibernate validation deployed to the IBM application server version 9

my hibernate setup is below
hibernate-core - 5.2.10.Final
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider as my jpa provider

encountered a ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl

I did't encounter this issue in WAS 8.5 with bean validation.

for the gradle dependencies

```
springFramewokVersion = '4.3.0.RELEASE'
apacheCxfVersion = '3.1.10'
jacksonVersion = '2.8.7'
aspectJVersion = '1.8.9'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs', version: "${apacheCxfVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-rs-client', version: "${apacheCxfVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-rs-service-description', version: "${apacheCxfVersion}"

    //jackson
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: "${jacksonVersion}"
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: "${jacksonVersion}"
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: "${jacksonVersion}"

    //spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: "${springFramewokVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: "${springFramewokVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: "${springFramewokVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: "${springFramewokVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: "${springFramewokVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: "${springFramewokVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: "${springFramewokVersion}"

    //aspect
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: "${aspectJVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: "${aspectJVersion}"

    //utility
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version:'0.6.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version:'4.5.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.7'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '0.7.7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.5'

    //persistence
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.10.Final' 

    //testing
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'
    compile group: 'org.jmockit', name: 'jmockit', version: '1.21'
    compile group: 'org.jmockit', name: 'jmockit-coverage', version: '1.21'

    //validation
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.1.0.Final'
    compile group: 'javax.el', name: 'javax.el-api', version: '3.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.el', version: '3.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '5.4.1.Final'

    //swagger
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger', version: "${apacheCxfVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'swagger-ui', version: '3.0.3'
```

for the controller

```
@POST
@Path("/authenticate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response authenticateCredentials(@BeanParam BaseRSParams params,
        @Valid @RequestBody AuthenticationParams authenticationParams) throws DirectoryServiceException {

    ldapService = (ILdapService) getService(LDAP_SERVICE_IMPL + params.getVersion());
    ldapService.isUserValid(authenticationParams.getUsername(), authenticationParams.getPassword());

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

for the persistence xml

```
<persistence-unit name="cifPersistenceUnit" >
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/> 
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

for the stacktrace

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1620)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1596)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:608)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:581)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:527)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:495)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:460)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:410)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:756)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:680)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:1117)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:301)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:255)
org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationProvider.validateParameters(BeanValidationProvider.java:116)
org.apache.cxf.validation.AbstractBeanValidationInterceptor.handleValidation(AbstractBeanValidationInterceptor.java:55)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor.handleValidation(JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor.java:55)
org.apache.cxf.validation.AbstractValidationInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractValidationInterceptor.java:72)
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:218)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4144)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2208)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader$CachingPersistenceProviderResolver.loadResolverClasses(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:160)
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader$CachingPersistenceProviderResolver.<init>(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:122)
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:80)
javax.persistence.Persistence.getProviders(Persistence.java:69)
javax.persistence.Persistence.access$000(Persistence.java:23)
javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:109)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:47)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:128)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:36)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1611)
... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:609)
com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:850)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:829)
com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:619)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:619)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:619)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader$CachingPersistenceProviderResolver.loadResolverClasses(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:142)
... 59 more
```

Answer (score 1):

In WebSphere Application Server Version 9.0, the default JPA Provider was switched from WSJPA/OpenJPA to EclipseLink. The exception stack shows that your application is trying to load the WSJPA JPA provider class which isn't visible if EclipseLink is set as your JPA provider (the default in WebSphere 9).

If you want to use WSJPA as your JPA provider, you can switch your default JPA provider by going to your administration console -> Expand Servers -> Application Servers -> Select your server -> Expand Container Services -> Default Java Persistence API Settings -> Under JPA specification, choose 2.0 and ensure that the Default persistence provider is set to "com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl"

Comment: dalia - i edit my question above, i added my persistence xml. setting the default jpa setting will just trigger if i don't have a jpa persistence unit available.

Comment: i dont have an issue on querying with hibernate jpa, i just encounter this issue on bean validation

Comment: Which JPA spec level do you have specified in your tWAS configuration?

Comment: Its in 2.1 with the default persistence provider, org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider

Comment: one in the ibm forum, advice me to add this custom properties to my websphere jvm -  
com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine = true. to disable websphere jaxrs engine, but still experiencing the same error

Comment: I see your other forum post and the replies there. I would recommend following the instructions in the link they attached in the reply (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tejb_jpa3rdparty.html) especially the part about classloading. It looks like the hibernate validator is trying to load the wsjpa provider which it will not find if JPA 2.1 is enabled.

Comment: @dalia  (ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/…) That's a classic theoretically-colorful but practically useless document.  Even setting class loaders to parent-last does not help. Setting jpa2.0 does not help. Had I not been forced to use WAS in the company that I work, WAS would have been banished a year back:)